# Ruby Gem Collapse Fish Shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, fish

whenever I use a command related to gem that is not in history it will break the terminal. in this example I was going to write 'gem check', it was the first time so this is waht happened:

```
Miguel@MacBook-Pro ~> gem ch
The function call stack limit has been exceeded. do you have an accidental infinite loop?
    - (line 1): type -all $argv;
                ^
in function 'which'
    called on line 4 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.2.0/share/fish/functions/type.fish
    with parameter list '-a -- -all'

in command substitution
    called on line 2 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.2.0/share/fish/functions/type.fish

in function 'type'
    called on line 1 of file -
    with parameter list '-all -a -- -all'
```

This output repeats again and again in an infinite loop.

This also happen if I wrote something else after a prevoius used command. i.e: gem update -s, the -s part will get the same behavior

Comment: Do you have any aliases or custom functions that override `gem`?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a bad fish shell theme installed. I have no issue running `gem check` on fish 2.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you have an alias called `which` that calls `type`. Since `type` is a function that in some paths (when called with "-a") calls `which`, this results in an "infinite" loop.

In the next fish version, this will be fixed by calling `command which` in the `type` function. For now, the solution is to remove the alias or call it something else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed I removed the alias which and everything is working as usual.

PD: you [or someone with the same username and avatar] suggest a patch on Fish's github, is a good idea to use it or should I wait til the next release?

Comment: Yeah, that's easy enough to apply - you can even do it with `funced type` (and then `funcsave type` to persist the changes) - all you need to do is replace `which` with `command which`.